# Random text string in messages

Tags: sms, factory-reset

Recently i factory reset my LG Tribute HD. As soon as setup compleated. I got a message from a random number.
Any clue what this is? It reminds me if stagefright.

[image]

Comment: The linked image cannot be opened

Comment: The number seems to be from your carrier. Although the message is somehow broken, may be an automatic internet configuration or a promotional message...

Comment: What's your carrier?

Comment: I use sprint as my carrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wild guess:** It's an encoded message from a terrorism organization telling about a scheduled event :)

**Serious Analysis:** Call your carrier support for more information. This looks like some internal information (metadata) that accidentally leaked out. I made this guess because that message

1. Uses colon for field separator (*very* common in Unix systems)
2. Contains a time stamp (1496949959776 is `19:25:59.776, Jun 8, 2017 UTC`)
3. Contains a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded data, which gives a 20-byte nonsense after decoding
4. Contains an unused number from Seville, Ohio
5. Contains a 32-character code in an unknown format

If you don't want to dig too deep or you're not so curious, then you can safely ignore it.

Comment: I'm actually extremely curious about it.  And that "unused" number looks familiar...